# Who played these characters at the end of Mockingjay Part 2?

Tags: the-hunger-games, actors, mockingjay

In the final scene of the (brilliant) film *Mockingjay Part 2*,

> Katniss and Peeta appear in a field together with their two young children.

I noticed in the end credits that

> both of the actors playing these children have the surname Lawrence.

Surely this is not a coincidence, since both the lead actress and the director of the film share the same surname. But they are not related, so which (if either) of them are the two new actors related to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Bear](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm7698729/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t43) and [Theodore](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm7698730/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t44) Lawrence are Jennifer Lawrence's nephews.

> "The one with Josh is her oldest nephew [Bear], and the one in her arms is her youngest nephew [Theo].”

([Source](http://www.jabberjays.net/2015/11/25/francis-lawrence-on-working-with-jennifer-lawrences-nephews/))